# Periods for bullet point items

Tags: punctuation, lists, periods

In a 'bulleted' list should items that happen to be complete sentences end with a period?

Comment: A duplicate with more answers: [Use of capitals and full stops in bullet points](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55048/use-of-capitals-and-full-stops-in-bullet-points).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Wikipedia style guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style#Bulleted_and_numbered_lists) mandates the following approach, which seems sensible to me given that they do have to maintain a large body of text from disparate authors.

> Use the same grammatical form for all
> elements in a list, and do not mix the
> use of sentences and sentence
> fragments as elements.
>
> - When the elements are complete sentences, they are formatted using
>   sentence case and a final period.
> - When the elements are sentence fragments, they are typically
>   introduced by a lead fragment ending
>   with a colon. When these elements are
>   titles of works, they retain the
>   original capitalization of the title.
>   Other elements are formatted
>   consistently in either sentence case
>   or lower case. Each element should end
>   with a semicolon, with a period
>   instead for the last element.
>   Alternatively (especially when the
>   elements are short), no final
>   punctuation is used at all.

Comment: Seems sensible, but note that this is one style guide. There are potentially as many different answers as there are style guides.